# MDX : Rename column titles as calculated Mmeber

Tags: mdx, jasperserver

I have an OLAP Mondrian cube published on JasperServer within MDX script

My cube looks like this:

[image]

The MDX code is the following:

```
select NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Time consumed]} ON COLUMNS,
  NON EMPTY Hierarchize({([Users.User].[All Users.Users],[Projects.Project].[All Projects.Projects],[Tasks.Task].[All Tasks.Tasks], [Imputations.Imputation].[All Imputations.Imputations])}) ON ROWS
from [cubeSifast]
```

As I see in the display view i have standr columns nomination, so how may I change for example :

**1.** the column headers titles (circled with blue line)

**2.** the children titles which are the names of dimensions (yellow)

I think that can be within the calculated members with MDX

> "with member as"

but how exatcly, any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MDX : Rename a calculated dimension ame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41122570/mdx-rename-a-calculated-dimension-ame)

Comment: It is a bad idea to repost the same question

Comment: first of all , here am asking about caclulated member , (then for the other question there no even answers , 3rd ; you had better to post a response then disqualify my question which , in the quality was better than the other one

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with a Set.

```
with
set myNewName
as
[Users.User].[All Users.Users].MEMBERS
select 
    NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Time consumed]} ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY Hierarchize({(myNewName,[Projects.Project].[All Projects.Projects],[Tasks.Task].[All Tasks.Tasks], [Imputations.Imputation].[All Imputations.Imputations])}) ON ROWS
from [cubeSifast]
```

Comment: Mondrian Error:Set expression 'myNewName' must be a set

Comment: could you try it again?

Comment: just to verify , shouldn't i make this : "with set [Users.User].[All Users.Users].MEMBERS as myNewName"  i doubt that it's inversed @mxix

Comment: no, the way i did it is the correct syntax. `WITH <MEMBER|SET> AS <definition>`